# Using C#, how to programmatically enable Azure Key Vault secret?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-keyvault

I need to programmatically enable / disable Azure Key Vault secrets in C#. I am able to disable a secret but I cannot figure out how to enable it. Here is the code:

```
//Setup client from Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets version 4.4.0
string keyVaultUrl = "…";
string tenantId = "…";
string clientId = "…";
string clientSecret = "…";
ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
_client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

 

//I am able to disable a secret
Azure.Response<KeyVaultSecret> response = await _client.GetSecretAsync(secretName, version: null, cancellationToken);
KeyVaultSecret secret = response.Value;
secret.Properties.Enabled = false;
_client.UpdateSecretProperties(secret.Properties);


//I am not able to enable a secret. Get error "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Version')"
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> secretPropertiesCollection = _client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync(cancellationToken);
await foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in secretPropertiesCollection)
{
    if (secretProperties.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == secretName.ToUpperInvariant())
    {
        secretProperties.Enabled = true;
        _client.UpdateSecretProperties(secretProperties);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: As the docs says for GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync "Individual secret versions are not listed in the response.". And it indirectly says what to to do about i "You can use the returned Name in subsequent calls to GetSecretAsync". That triggers why you just don't call GetSecretAsync like you have done for disabling the secret?

Comment: GetSecretAsync throws an exception for disabled secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Java offering for the Key Vault SDK but can shed some light on this. It looks that the `UpdateSecretProperties` method expects a version of the secret to be included in the `SecretProperties` passed to it. We don't do this in Java so I would have to have a chat with my C# counterpart to figure if this is a bug or the intended behavior. That said, **you should still be able to enable a disabled secret programatically.** If you know the name of the secret in question, you can call a `SecretClient.GetPropertiesOfSecretVersions()` method to obtain the `SecretProperties` of each version of the secret, which also include the version itself. You can then update the `Enabled` property to `true` and use the `UpdateSecretProperties` as you originally intended.

I'm not a C# expert but I think this is what it should look like:

```cs
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> secretPropertiesCollection =
    _client.GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync("secretName", cancellationToken);

await foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in secretPropertiesCollection)
{
    secretProperties.Enabled = true;
    _client.UpdateSecretProperties(secretProperties);

    return;
}
```

Alternatively, if you still have a handle for the original `KeyVaultSecret` object, you can set its `Enabled` property back to `true` and use the `SetSecret()` operation to update it, although this would not create a new version for the secret as opposed to the option I laid out above.

Comment: Thank you @vcolin7 I think there should be two sets of APIs (let's call it "admin" and "access") in the SDK because there are two very different use-cases. Our use-case is to build our own UI to Azure Key Vault so that business users manage secrets without access to the portal. We would use the "admin" APIs which should be able to read/write secrets regardless if the secret is enabled. The other use-case is when an app needs read-only access to secrets and it can use the "access" APIs which can blow up if the secret is not enabled - for this use-case, it is the same as a non-existing secret.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Version')
> ```

As commented by @Ralf, This is a known exception caused when the [UpdateSecretProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.updatesecretproperties?view=azure-dotnet) method is returned with a null version which is because the [GetPropertiesOfSecrets()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.getpropertiesofsecrets?view=azure-dotnet) method doesn't return individual secret's versions which is returned as null.

> Individual secret versions are not listed in the response. This operation requires the secrets/list permission.

Currently, the get() permissions only work for enabled secrets. The only way that worked for me is to enable the secrets from portal.

[image]